# Python can not find an installed module in the conda env

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, anaconda, conda, pydub

I'm using python with anaconda.

`AttributeError: module 'pydub' has no attribute 'playback'`

I get the error above when I try to run the following statement:

`speech = pydub.AudioSegment.from_mp3("temp_speak.mp3")`

`pydub.playback.play(speech)`

the problem is , I can see there is a module called playback in the auto completition of visual studio code , besides that , when I get to the

`~/anaconda3/envs/env_name/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pydub`

I can see that there is a file named playback and its not corrupted.

here is the output of ls :

`audio_segment.py  generators.py     playback.py   scipy_effects.py`
`effects.py        __init__.py       pyaudioop.py  silence.py`
`exceptions.py     logging_utils.py  __pycache__   utils.py`

And I'm sure that I'm activating the environment before I run my script.

Comment: Unfamiliar with `pydub`, but I would expect the proper syntax to look like `speech.play()`

Comment: speech just gets the audio segment and saves it on a variable. In pydub , you play the audio segments with the playback module. Thanks for the answer anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by importing the playback module serperately. Still can not understand why the interpreter thinks playback module is an attribute.